# Bash Script can't run: Command Not Found

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I made a script that will run as a cron task, executing itself in 5 minute intervals. The objective it's for him to read a log file, that is created daily, using a pre-defined pattern. It creates a .flag file for keeping track of that was already been read, if it matches the pattern it runs a .sh script for restarting the services.

I already resolved a problem with the same script about wrong Line Terminators if that could be relevant for the solution.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LAST_POS_FILE="last_position.flag"

PATTERN='ERROR [pt.gsoft.oasis.platform.plugins.mediaconverter.ejb.messages.MediaConverterMDB]'

LOG_FILE='/var/local/log/server.log'

if [ ! -f "$LAST_POS_FILE" ]; then
        echo 0 > "$LAST_POS_FILE"

fi

LAST_POS=$(cat "$LAST_POS_FILE")

CURR_LOG=$(date+"%Y-%m-%d")

if [ "$LOG_FILE.$CURR_LOG" -nt "$LOG_FILE" ]; then
        LOG_FILE="$LOG_FILE.$CURR_LOG"
fi

if [[ "$LOG_FILE" -nt "$LOG_FILE" ]]; then
        LINE=$(grep -E "$PATTERN" "$LOG_FILE" | awk -F: '{print $1}')

        if [ -n "$LINE" ]; then
                if [ "$LINE" -gt "$LAST_POS" ]; then
                        echo "$LINE" > "$LAST_POS_FILE"

                        ./teste.sh
                fi
        fi
fi

# end of file #
```

My terminal output is

```
filipe@filipe-virtual-machine:~$ sudo ./restarScript.sh
sudo: ./restarScript.sh: command not found
```

For the record, I'm doing the testing on another machine, since I don't have a testing ambient, the target machine is running Red-Hat if that's something to have in account.

I used [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net) and [JDoodle](https://jdoodle.com) for a more detailed error description.

Shellcheck Output:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
No issues detected!

$
```

JDoodle Output:

```
jdoodle.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
jdoodle.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
jdoodle.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
jdoodle.sh: line 8: $'\r': command not found
jdoodle.sh: line 35: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Command exited with non-zero status 2
```

I suppose the `$'\r'` \ Line Terminator errors are irrelevant since it's already been solved, I just have the syntax error pending

Comment: can you do $ls -ltr and make sure script is there? Also make sure sudo command is installed

Comment: With `ls -ltr` the file shows, one of the line was `-rw-rw-r-- 1 filipe filipe  754 mar 21 12:39 restarScript.sh` and writing `sudo` in the terminal shows me the usages cases.

Comment: can you try to add chmod +x restarScript.sh command to make it exexutable. If not executable it should be different error. But still +x permission is missing

Comment: it looks like something is missing $PATH variable. Can you  do `echo $PATH` as well? Looks like /bin/bash should be part of variable. Maybe instead of /bin/bash you should try #!/bin/sh or you have to add bash script as default script of current user

Comment: Is that shell Bash? if not, may be `./script` behaves differently.

Comment: @FariZ the chmod +x fixed it, the script is trying to run, now i'm having another error now, `./restarScript.sh: 16: date+%Y-%m-%d: not found`
(Fixed it putting a space between date and +)

Comment: put space. replace "date+%Y-%m-%d" with `date +%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Anytime I see `\r` in output I ask "Has your code ever been near an MS-Windows machine?" .. If so, you seem to have Windows line endings of `\r\n` and you'll need to get rid of them. First, `cat -vet myScript | head -10`. If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, the `dos2unix myScxript` will fix it. Good luck.

Comment: @FariZ : PATH is not relevant here (regarding the posted error message), because the OP is providing the path explicitly.

Comment: From the error message, I would conclude that the file does not exist. To verify this, do a `ls ./restarScript.sh`. If the file is present, check the #! line of the script (`head -n 1 ./restarScript.sh`).

Comment: I don't understand why you mention here JDoodle. How did you use JDoodle, and why?

Comment: The error comes because your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) actually says `#!/bin/bash^M` where the `^M` is actually an invisible control character, and you have no command named `/bin/bash^M`

Comment: Tangentially, [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score -2):

pasted script has issue.
replace `CURR_LOG=$(date+"%Y-%m-%d")` with `CURR_LOG=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")`

Also looks you copied from Windows OS and EOL is different than linux.
try `dos2unix` to convert EOL and execute again.